# How to run Red5 application in eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, red5

I am trying to make simple basic Red5 application on eclipse Indigo/Kepler IDE version . I have followed video tutorials given by website [Red5 installation tutorials](http://www.red5guide.com/)!. But when I import red5 server source that is being fetched via `svn checkout http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only` command. The code has lot of errors for which I even add libraries from lib of red5 server & added external jars and even installed plugins of maven & spring framework.But still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfully set up the red5 workspace, following step by step the **Red5 Media Server - Workspace Setup Guide** on the red5 official website ( http://www.red5.org/red5-ide-plugin/ )

Here's the direct link
https://docs.google.com/document/d/11ju06wbnEdC3ay0VuUxpKcXIoSx5NaHruNKuZQ4yOCk

Comment: [!Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986367/red5-server-import-source-code-gives-maven-repository-error)

Comment: I had also troubles in building red5.
Have you tried to do everything from the beginning, following the guide?

Comment: [!plz find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007387/bug-in-debugging-red5-server-as-java-application-inside-eclipse)