# Bug in debugging Red5 server as Java Application inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, red5

I am following
 [Red5 Media Server - Workspace Setup Guide - r4737](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11ju06wbnEdC3ay0VuUxpKcXIoSx5NaHruNKuZQ4yOCk/edit?pli=1#)!

I am able to build Red5 distribution and rename distribution jar files  i.e completed upto step 6.But when I followed step 7 - `Run inside of eclipse` failed to debug it as java application -

```
Red5 root: /home/yuvraj/Documents/RED5/red5 java code all/java/server/trunk
Configuation root: /home/yuvraj/Documents/RED5/red5 java code all/java/server/trunk/conf
Red5 server jar was not found, using fallback.
URL list: [file:/home/yuvraj/Documents/RED5/red5%20java%20code%20all/java/server/trunk/red5.jar]
Bootstrap exception: null
Bootstrap exit
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:172)
    at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:96)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:117)
    at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:48)
```

I couldn't find conf directory neither in `/home/yuvraj/Documents/RED5/red5 java code all/java/server/trunk/` `nor in /Red5_server/bin`  while setting classpath in java debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed step by step the guide, you are probably using the 1.0.2 RC4.
Try this now:

- Extract the `red5-server-1.0.2-RC4.zip` from the target folder to a custom folder
  (I have it in c:\red5-server-1.0.2-RC4 )
- Copy `red5.jar` and `bootstrap.jar` in the place you extracted red5. (In my case c:\red5-server-1.0.2-RC4\ )
- Repeat the step 7 in the Guide and be carefull at point L.

  `conf` directory is in \red5-server-1.0.2-RC4\

Comment: Even I successfully build Red5 distribution in step 6 but got error while building it i.e at [**link build log**](http://122.160.124.118/testxml/Debugerror.txt). I ignored it. Will this create any issue?

Comment: It shouldn't. What is your problem now?

Comment: I have tried what you said but still getting above mentioned error. I extracted red5-server-1.0.2-RC4.zip placed and added conf folder to debug as Java -> classpath of **red5_server** code.

Comment: How do I change my config root i.e `Configuation root: /home/yuvraj/Documents/RED5/red5 java code all/java/server/trunk/conf` to the path of conf directory is in `\red5-server-1.0.2-RC4\` ? I think then conf root will be changed and error will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

From the output you've shown, I'd assume you're missing the lib directory and its contents. This wiki link should help: https://code.google.com/p/red5/wiki/ServerWontStart#Bootstrap_exception